# Printing in the same line in python

Tags: python, python-2.5

I am quite new in python and I need your help.

I have a file like this:

```
>chr14_Gap_2
ACCGCGATGAAAGAGTCGGTGGTGGGCTCGTTCCGACGCGCATCCCCTGGAAGTCCTGCTCAATCAGGTGCCGGATGAAGGTGGT
GCTCCTCCAGGGGGCAGCAGCTTCTGCGCGTACAGCTGCCACAGCCCCTAGGACACCGTCTGGAAGAGCTCCGGCTCCTTCTTG
acacccaggactgatctcctttaggatggactggctggatcttcttgcagtccaaggggctctcaagagt
………..
>chr14_Gap_3
ACCGCGATGAAAGAGTCGGTGGTGGGCTCGTTCCGACGCGCATCCCCTGGAAGTCCTGCTCAATCAGGTGCCGGATGAAGGTGGT
GCTCCTCCAGGGGGCAGCAGCTTCTGCGCGTACAGCTGCCACAGCCCCTAGGACACCGTCTGGAAGAGCTCCGGCTCCTTCTTG
acacccaggactgatctcctttaggatggactggctggatcttcttgcagtccaaggggctctcaagagt
………..
```

One string as a tag and one string the dna sequence.
I want to calculate the number of the N letters and the number of the lower case letters and take the percentage.
I wrote the following script which works but I have a problem in printing.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys


if len (sys.argv) != 2 :
  print "Usage: If you want to run this python script  you have to put the fasta file that     includes the desert area's sequences as arument"
  sys.exit (1)

  fasta_file = sys.argv[1]

#This script reads the sequences of the desert areas (fasta files) and calculates the   persentage of the Ns and the repeats.

 fasta_file = sys.argv[1]
 f = open(fasta_file, 'r')

content = f.readlines()
x = len(content)
#print x
for i in range(0,len(content)):
      if (i%2 == 0):
            content[i].strip()
            name = content[i].split(">")[1]
            print name,  #the "," makes the print command to avoid to print a new line
     else:
            content[i].strip()
            numberOfN = content[i].count('N')
            #print numberOfN
            allChar =  len(content[i])
            lowerChars = sum(1 for c in content[i] if c.islower())
            Ns_persentage = 100 * (numberOfN/float(allChar))
            lower_persentage = 100 * (lowerChars/float(allChar))
            waste = Ns_persentage + lower_persentage
            print ("The waste persentage is: %s" % (round(waste)))
            #print ("The persentage of Ns is: %s and the persentage of repeats is: %s" %   (Ns_persentage,lower_persentage))

    #print (name + waste)
```

The thing is that it can print the tag in the first line and the waste variable in the second one like this:

```
chr10_Gap_18759
The waste persentage is: 52.0
```

How can I print it in the same line, tab separated?

eg

```
chr10_Gap_18759      52.0 
chr10_Gap_19000      78.0 
…….
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide a sample input and what do you want to see as a result for that exact input.

Answer (score 1):

You can print it with:

```
print name, "\t", round(waste)
```

If you are using python 2.X
I would make some modification to your code. There is the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) module of python to manage the arguments from the command line. I would do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse
# To use the arguments 
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("fasta_file", help = "The fasta file to be processed ", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

f= open(args.fasta_file, "r")
content = f.readlines()
f.close()

x = len(content)
for i in range(x):
      line = content[i].strip()
      if (i%2 == 0):
          #The first time it will fail, for the next occasions it will be printed as you wish
            try:
                print bname, "\t", round(waste)
            except:
                pass
            name = line.split(">")[1]
     else:
            numberOfN = line.count('N')
            allChar =  len(line)
            lowerChars = sum(1 for c in content[i] if c.islower())
            Ns_persentage = 100 * (numberOfN/float(allChar))
            lower_persentage = 100 * (lowerChars/float(allChar))
            waste = Ns_persentage + lower_persentage
# To print the last case you need to do it outside the loop
print name, "\t", round(waste)
```

You can also print it like the other answer with `print("{}\t{}".format(name, round(waste)))`

I am not sure about the use of `i%2`, Note that if the sequence uses and odd number of lines you'll will not get the name of the next sequence until the same event occurs. I would check if the line begin with ">" then use store the name, and sum the characters of the next line.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I tried that but it gives me syntax error at the following line:
with open(args.fasta_file, "r") as f:

When im using the printing statement it prints everything in a line but like that:
('chr15_Gap_1513\n', '\t', 75.0)

Comment: Now it should be correct, I modified the print function because it seems you use python 2.x. I also modified the .format expression test it now if it works

Answer (score 0):

Don't print the `name` when `(i%2 == 0)`, just save it in variable and print in the next iteration together with the percentage:

```
 print("{0}\t{1}".format(name, round(waste)))
```

> This method of string formatting ([new in version 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)) is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the % formatting described in [String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) in new code.

Comment: unfortunately the str.format() function doesnt work.   
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: What version of Python do you use? 2.2? Well, if so, you have to use % operator instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the indentation and redundancy:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""
This script reads the sequences of the desert areas (fasta files) and calculates the percentage of the Ns and the repeats.
2014-10-05 v1.0 by Vasilis
2014-10-05 v1.1 by Llopis
2015-02-27 v1.2 by Cees Timmerman
"""

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("fasta_file", help="The fasta file to be processed.", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.fasta_file, "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0] == '>':
            name = line.split(">")[1]
            print name,
        else:
            numberOfN = line.count('N')
            allChar = len(line)
            lowerChars = sum(1 for c in line if c.islower())
            Ns_percentage = 100 * (numberOfN/float(allChar))
            lower_percentage = 100 * (lowerChars/float(allChar))
            waste = Ns_percentage + lower_percentage

            print "\t", round(waste)  # Note: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round
```

Fed:

```
>chr14_Gap_2
ACCGCGATGAAAGAGTCGGTGGTGGGCTCGTTCCGACGCGCATCCCCTGGAAGTCCTGCTCAATCAGGTGCCGGATGAAGGTGGTGCTCCTCCAGGGGGCAGCAGCTTCTGCGCGTACAGCTGCCACAGCCCCTAGGACACCGTCTGGAAGAGCTCCGGCTCCTTCTTGacacccaggactgatctcctttaggatggactggctggatcttcttgcagtccaaggggctctcaagagt
>chr14_Gap_3
ACCGCGATGAAAGAGTCGGTGGTGGGCTCGTTCCGACGCGCATCCCCTGGAAGTCCTGCTCAATCAGGTGCCGGATGAAGGTGGTGCTCCTCCAGGGGGCAGCAGCTTCTGCGCGTACAGCTGCCACAGCCCCTAGGACACCGTCTGGAAGAGCTCCGGCTCCTTCTTGacacccaggactgatctcctttaggatggactggctggatcttcttgcagtccaaggggctctcaagagt
```

Gives:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe -u "dna.py" fasta.txt
Process started >>>
chr14_Gap_2     29.0
chr14_Gap_3     29.0
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 0)
```

Using my favorite Python IDE: [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with [NppExec plugin](https://gist.github.com/CTimmerman/3fc259d7867c38f6919e).